# RSpec-2 with Rails 2.3.x

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2

How can I update to Rspec-2 with a Rails 2.3.x project? I can not move to Rails 3.x, however i would need to have Rspec-2 working instead of Rspec-1. Thanks for your advices!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Rspec 2 does not work with Rails 2.3.x. Use Rspec 1.

Answer (score 0):

The 'official' rspec-rails 2 gem does not support rails 2.x.

You can use this this gem instead:

https://github.com/rsanheim/rspec-rails23

It works well for model specs, but does not support controller and view specs.